# Linq to SQL multiple conditional where clauses

Tags: c#, sql, linq

At the moment I am retrieving my results as follows :

```
public List<claim> GetClaims()
{
    return _db.claims.OrderBy(cl => cl.claimId).ToList();
}
```

But now I am trying to add up to 8 conditional where clauses based on filters above my listview.

So I turned into:

```
public List<claim> GetFilteredClaims(string submissionId, string claimId,
                                     string organization, string status,
                                     string filterFromDate, string filterToDate,
                                     string region, string approver)
{
    return _db.claims.Where(cl => cl.submissionId == 5).ToList();
}
```

How can I do a check for each filter to add a where clause only if they contain a value?

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8841339/138938

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't just keep filtering the results by calling `.Where` several times. Because of the deferred execution of LINQ to SQL it will all be executed in one SQL statement:

```
public List<claim> GetFilteredClaims(string submissionId, string claimId,
                                     string organization, string status,
                                     string filterFromDate, string filterToDate,
                                     string region, string approver)
{
    IQueryable<claim> filteredClaims = _db.claims;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(submissionId))
    {
        filteredClaims = filteredClaims.Where(claim => claim.submissionId == submissionId);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(claimId))
    {
        filteredClaims = filteredClaims.Where(claim => claim.claimId == claimId);
    }

    ...

    return filteredClaims.ToList();
}
```

If you will ever need to add OR conditions, you could take a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: Just thought I'd say thanks for this answer.  This helped me out a lot with a problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: +1 for PredicateBuilder - that is really the most flexible way

Answer (score 0):

You could group each filter option with an OR null condition, and chain them all together with AND, like so:

```
public List<claim> GetFilteredClaims(string submissionId, string claimId, string organization, string status, string filterFromDate, string filterToDate, string region, string approver)
    {
        return _db.claims
            .Where(cl => (cl.submissionId == submissionId || submissionId == null)
            && (cl.claimId == claimId || claimId == null)
            && so on and so on... ).ToList();

    }
```

So if submissionId == null and claimId == "123", it would only filter the results on claimId. You could replace each `null` with an empty string or whatever your "no value" condition is.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LINQKIT http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx  It will allow you to build predicate

Here is a code that I use but read the documentation above.  The predicate will allow you to chain up a bunch of OR or AND or combination of it.

```
private static IEnumerable<SurveyResult> filterData(string firstName, string lastName, List<SurveyResult> results)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SurveyResult>();


    IEnumerable<SurveyResult> a;
    if (excludeBadData)

    if (firstName != string.Empty)
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(firstName.ToLower()));
    }

    if (lastName != string.Empty)
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(lastName.ToLower()));
    }


    a = from r in results.AsQueryable().Where(predicate) select r;
    return a;
}
```